# How to concatenate a string and an integer to get a three digit number

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, int, concatenation

I am in a beginner's course and I made this code but it does not work

```
random_number = str(random.randrange (1, 1000))
random_number_length = (len (random_number))
zero_number = ("0" * 3 - (random_number_length))
final_number = (random_number_length + random_number)
print (final_number)
```

The final output needs to look something like:

```
004
```

instead of:

```
4
```

I need to get a three digit number even if the generated number is 89 or 7.

When I attempt this I get the error:

```
    zero_number = ("0" * 3 - (random_number_length))
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'int'
```

I'm guessing it has something to do with a string and an integer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Above answers are more useful (you don't have to reinvent the wheel), but to use your own code:

```
import random

# Get the random number
random_number = str(random.randrange (1, 1000))

# Check number of digits in the number
random_number_length = len (random_number)

# Use the number of digits to get the number of zeros
zero_number = "0" * (3 - (random_number_length))

# Concatenate zero_number with random_number
final_number = zero_number + random_number

print (final_number)
# 006
```

Try to use less brackets: these are sometimes confusing. But your main problem:

```
zero_number = ("0" * 3 - (random_number_length))
```

Multiplication comes before subtraction, so it is:

1. `"0" * 3`  => is a string
2. `"000" - random_number_length` => string - int = ?

You cannot concatenate two different types (here `int` and `string`).

Answer (score 6):

Python strings have a zfill method that you can use to pad your string with leading zeros.

```
>>> '1'.zfill(3)
'001'
>>> '89'.zfill(3)
'089'
>>> '189'.zfill(3)
'189'
```

As zfill is not allowed:

```
>>> def f(n):
...     s = str(n)
...     return '0' * (3 - len(s)) + s
... 
>>> 
>>> for x in [1, 11, 111]: print(f(x))
... 
001
011
111
```

Comment: I'm not allowed to use the zfill method. But thank you either way.

Answer (score 3):

As an alternative to `zfill` you can use [`rjust`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.rjust):

```
>>> '1'.rjust(3, '0')
'001'
>>> '89'.rjust(3, '0')
'089'
>>> '189'.rjust(3, '0')
'189'
```

Or format:

```
>>> "{:0>3}".format('1')
'001'
>>> "{:0>3}".format('89')
'089'
>>> "{:0>3}".format('189')
'189'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    >>> '%03d' % 1
    '001'
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you're doing this for educational reasons, the answer is that operators (such as *, +, - etc) have precedence.

You are writing:

```
zero_number = ("0" * 3 - (random_number_length))
```

The operator `*` is used first, then the operator `-`.

This is what is really happening:

```
# assuming number is 89, so random_number_length is 2

zero_number = ("0" * 3 - (random_number_length))
zero_number = ("0" * 3 - (2))
zero_number = ("000" - (2))
zero_number = ("000" - 2)

# error - you can't subtract a number (an integer) from a string.
```

You need to force the subtraction to happen before the string multiplication.

```
zero_number = "0" * (3 - random_number_length)
```

This is the final code, formatted properly (I've removed the unnecessary parentheses, and the unnecessary spaces)

```
import random

random_number = str(random.randrange(1, 1000))
random_number_length = len(random_number)
zero_number = "0" * (3 - random_number_length)
final_number = zero_number + random_number
print(final_number)
```

You were also adding the wrong thing to the random number - you should have been adding the "zero_number" variable in (your) line 4, which you created in the above line (your line 3)